# How to calculate time taken by a function to execute in Deno

Tags: deno

I need to get execution time in milliseconds. How can we do using Deno?

Comment: why doesn't `performance.now()` work?

Answer (score 9):

You should use Performance API.

`--allow-hrtime` flag is required if you want high-resolution time measurement, otherwise it **won't throw** a permission denied error but it will be an integer instead, losing precision.

```js
const t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`Call to doSomething took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);
```

Or `console.time`

```
console.time('foo');
doSomething();
console.timeEnd('foo'); // foo: 400ms
```